# More than two awaits in runBlocking

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a problem with await in Kotlin, if I use only 2 `await`s, this `runBlocking` block works for 10 seconds, but when I try to use 4 `await`s, it works for 20 seconds. As I understand, there are only two async threads in runBlocking. How can I increase this count?

```
fun testFun() {
    val z1 = async { Thread.sleep(10000) }
    val z2 = async { Thread.sleep(10000) }
    val z3 = async { Thread.sleep(10000) }
    val z4 = async { Thread.sleep(10000) }

    runBlocking {
        z1.await()
        z2.await()
        z3.await()
        z4.await() // works 20 seconds
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `async { ... }` you let the standard library choose a default context to run your coroutines in. I guess in your case it happens to be a thread pool with just two threads.

To gain control over what happens, use

```
async(MyDispatcher) { ... }
```

where, as a simple example, you can define

```
val MyDispatcher = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4).asCoroutineDispatcher()
```

Keep in mind that shutting down the thread pool is now your responsibility:

```
MyDispatcher.close()
```